# Class diagrams to show relation between classes?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Are class diagrams in visual studio supposed to show relation between classes, for eg. 1 : many.

```
public class User
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public List<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class Role {
    public int RoleId {get; set;}
    public User User {get; set;}
    public string UserId {get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit**:
To clarify.. Class diagram generally isn't supposed to show relations (1:n, m:n etc.) because those relations are for database tables (entities). Classic class diagram is more suited for analysis and design, so it shows associations instead of relations.

Original answer:
Yes you can show 'relations', but you wont see any numbers afaik. It has its own way of showing. Numbers are shown in Entity Framework model for example.

*How to show associations:*
Move classes into diagram, and then right click on property Roles and pick `Show as collection association`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show more advanced associations [here](http://modeling.codeplex.com/) is an addin for Visual studio from CodePlex.